# Does class that is being called from Process Builder also runs in system Mode?

Tags: apex, process-builder, invocable-method

I am having global class "with sharing" and invocable method in that, I am aware that Process Builder runs in system mode, however I am having confusion around the class which is getting called from Process builder will also run in system mode? 
The reason I am asking this is because, security scanner suggested me to add CRUD checks in this class, however I want to run all logic in system context, so I am thinking to make it as false positive(I will be updating it to without sharing)
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

It will run in user context.The only time it runs in system context is when you explicitly mark the class as "without sharing."